# Include Taxonomy Terms in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a search page with a new instance of `wp_query` I am passing a string into `s` to get a part number which is currently a taxonomy term. Is there a way to include to the taxonomy term in a custom `wp_query`? Happy help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can query posts by a taxonomy value like in the example below:

```
$query_string = 'francis';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',         // your taxonomy name
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $query_string,    // the slug you want to search for - which in your case is passed through the query string
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

To access the query string, use `get_search_query()`.